# Explaining the DHR superselection theory through specific examples

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, second-quantization

The [DHR superselection theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/DHR+superselection+theory) is an important result in the framework of [algebraic quantum field theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0602036) that categorizes the set of all physically admissable superselection sectors of an observable algebra $\mathfrak{A}$. A physically admissable superselection sector is a representation $\pi$ of $\mathfrak{A}$ that becomes unitarily equivalent to the vacuum reresentation $\pi_0$, when restricted to the causal complement of any sufficiently large double cone ("DHR condition"):
$$\pi |_{\mathfrak{A}(O')}\cong \pi_0 |_{\mathfrak{A}(O')}.\tag{DHR}$$
Then it is [shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0602036) that for any such representation $\pi$, there exists a localized transportable endomorphism $\rho\in \mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{A})$ such that $\pi\cong\pi_0\circ\rho$. The collection of all such representations and endomorphisms forms the DHR category.

These definitions are extremely abstract. **Could someone help me understand the DHR condition and $\rho$ through specific examples** (e.g. using free particle models)? For example, consider a fermionic system with $SU(2)$ internal symmetry on a lattice. The observable algebra is generated by $SU(2)$ invariant fermion bilinears acting on neighboring sites, e.g. $\sum_{s=\uparrow,\downarrow}\psi^\dagger_{\vec{x},s}\psi_{\vec{y},s}$, $\psi^\dagger_{\vec{x},\uparrow}\psi^\dagger_{\vec{y},\downarrow}$. Let $\pi_0$ be the vacuum representation generated by the empty state $|0\rangle$. Then,

(1). What are all the representations $\pi$ that satisfy the DHR condition?

(2). How to define the endomorphism $\rho$ for each $\pi$?

[Note: Though DHR theory was originally formulated in relativistic context, it seems that the theory can be adapted to lattice systems as well, so I'm considering a lattice example  for simplicity. Feel free to go back to the relativistic case if necessary, the base line is, I want specific examples that illustrate the DHR condition and explicit construction of $\rho$.]

Comment: The DHR condition is $\pi |_{\mathfrak{A}(O')}\cong \pi_0 |_{\mathfrak{A}(O')}$ for every double cone $O$ (not only for sufficiently large cones).